# how to acces the responseText in the jqxhr.complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery

first of all i'm a complete javascript and jQuery noob so i'm sorry if this question is dumb. but i really haven't found the answer in the jQuery documentation or on google

i'm trying to perform an action on the response when the request is completed 
but i can't access responseText. i was under the impression the an jqxhr objext has a member responseText. but i get the following error 'responseText is not defined'.

```
this.load = function(fileName, actionFunction){
    var jqxhr = $.post(SERVER,{command : "load", filename : fileName})
    .complete(function(){ 
        actionFunction(responseText);
    });
}
```

EDIT

if i do

```
.complete(function(responseText){ actionFunction(responseText);}
```

or what Dave Ward suggest

i don't get an error but nothing happens

i know it isn't the  actionFunction() because if i input a string manually for testing purposes it does what i expect it to do.

when trying to see what parameter gets past on (prinintg it to the console in actionfunction)  i get [object Object]; even when trying to convert it to a string (String(parameter))

END EDIT

what am i doing wrong or how do i access responseText in the .complete function ?

tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.post` method is shorthand for a call to `$.ajax` with certain parameters predefined.

From [the documentation on the `ajax` function from jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the `complete` callback is passed *two* parameters: `jqXHR` and `textStatus`, where `jqXHR` is the actual `XMLHTTPRequest` object.

So it's the **second** parameter you want to pass to your handler:

```
.complete(function(jqXHR, responseText) {
  actionFunction(responseText);
});
```

Note that, as [Dave Ward says in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686062/how-to-acces-the-responsetext-in-the-jqxhr-complete-function/6686154#6686154), `responseText` in this case is really just a status indicator, like "success" or "error" (hence jQuery's name for it, "textStatus"). Given you have the word "response" in your variable name, I'm guessing (like he is) that you probably want the `success` callback instead of `complete`:

```
.success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  actionFunction(renderDataToString(data));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't capturing that response parameter in your anonymous function, so it isn't defined when you call actionFunction from within.  You could fix that like this:

```
.complete(function(responseText) {
  actionFunction(responseText);
});
```

Better yet, you can take advantage of JavaScript's functional nature and just pass the function itself in as the callback to .complete:

```
.complete(actionFunction);
```

Your actionFunction will automatically be called with the parameter you expect.

Comment: in both cases nothing happens when printing out out the parameter given to actionFunction in firebug i get [object Object] ; i tried using String(parameter) but that didn't work

Comment: From what it sounds like you're trying to do, I think you want the .success callback instead of .complete. Its first parameter is the data returned from your POST. .complete is more general purpose, and passes the jqXHR and status in as parameters, not the raw response itself.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, you were right. I have chosen Dan Tao as answer because your answer here was as a comment